# Need a short simple aggregated function SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a database base with a table named "extract1" with a column named "contactsphonenumber". I am trying to find what specific phone number appears the most.

Attempt 1:

```sql
SELECT MAX(COUNT(contactscellphone))
FROM extract1
GROUP BY contactscellphone;
```

Attempt 2:

```sql
SELECT MAX(contactscellphone)
FROM extract1
GROUP BY contactscellphone
(
    SELECT COUNT(contactscellphone)
    FROM extract1
    GROUP BY contactscellphone
);
```

Attempt 1 Error:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Cannot perform an aggregate
>   function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Attemp 2 Error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'select'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'.

Comment: _"Need a short simple aggregated function SQL query"_ isn't really a good question for SO, there ins't even a question there.

Comment: Probably learn to write SQL query will be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`:

```
select top (1) contactscellphone
from extract1g
group by contactscellphone
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you want all top values when there are ties, use `top (1) with ties`.

Comment: "ties" are showing multiple records when there is a "tie" for the `TOP` spot(s). So what if 2 or more phone numbers all tie for the most records?

Comment: @daShier . . . Then use `top (1) with ties`, as suggested in the answer.